# How to achieve inverted color in Windows 7 (like Compiz Negative)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, colors, accessibility

How can I achieve Compiz Negative effect in Windows 7?

[Screenshot showing what Compiz Negative effect is like](http://www.dhyra.com/2008/08/relieve-eye-strain-with-compiz-effect.html)

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> (High Contrast) doesn't cut it. Compiz Negative inverts color on every part of the screen, which High Contrast doesn't do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open up your start menu and type "Magnifier" in the search box. Open the Magnifier utility and zoom to 100%. Now click the sprocket to open up the preferences menu. There should be an option to "Invert colours".

You will have to leave the Magnifier utility running in the background, but this is an easy and native way of accomplishing what you want.

The settings of the utility are saved when closing it, so if you pin it to your taskbar you'll be able to invert colours on the go.

Comment: Using magnifier in full screen mode makes my the aero feature crash after few times. Does anyone have another solution ?

Comment: I am tired of Eclipse (IDE) being difficult to skin to a dark-background color scheme so I am trying this method but it does not address ClearType so the white-on-black text has fringes of color. It's terribly ugly. :(

Answer (score 11):

Actually, there is another solution, called *NegativeScreen*.

It's a little program I created, after I found no other simple and convenient solution.

[You can try it out here](http://arcanesanctum.net/negativescreen/).

Comment: This is awesome! The smart inversion 2 works so well! Thanks so much for developing this and making it available.

Comment: This one works out much better. Thanks for making this available!

Comment: And you released the source! It would be even more awesome if you put in a free project hosting like Google Code.

Comment: A lot of the modes are seriously painful on the eyes when ClearType is enabled, but a few of them do work well. Nice little app. Particularly dig the smooth transitions

Comment: @Yaurthek, can you further develop it and provide a possibility to use the color invert only on certain processes? Basically, all I care about is my ugly white Skype I want to turn into a black one. Thank you.